# Create "counter" array in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table in postgresql-9.4.2 with an array column.

```
create schema test_schema;
create table test_schema.test_table;
(
    array_column int[]
);
insert into test_schema.test_table values
    (ARRAY[5,12,6,2]),
    (ARRAY[51,4,2]),
    (ARRAY[2]),
    (ARRAY[3,16]);
```

Which will look like this

```
    | array_column |
    | integer[]    |
--------------------
  1 | {5,12,6,2}   |
  2 | {51,4,2}     |
  3 | {2}          |
  4 | {3,16}       |
```

I want to query this table, and add a column to my query which is an array counting from 1 to the size of the array.

I have figured out how to create an array of the same size as shown below

```
select
    array_column,
    array_fill(1,array[array_length(array_column,1)],array[1]) as counter
from
    test_schema.test_table;
```

which returns the following results

```
    | array_column | counter    |
    | integer[]    | integer[]  |
---------------------------------
  1 | {5,12,6,2}   | {1,1,1,1}  |
  2 | {51,4,2}     | {1,1,1}    |
  3 | {2}          | {1}        |
  4 | {3,16}       | {1,1}      |
```

I was going to take the rolling sum of counter which would give me the desired result, but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the desired result:

```
    | array_column | counter    |
    | integer[]    | integer[]  |
---------------------------------
  1 | {5,12,6,2}   | {1,2,3,4}  |
  2 | {51,4,2}     | {1,2,3}    |
  3 | {2}          | {1}        |
  4 | {3,16}       | {1,2}      |
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function [`generate_subscripts(array anyarray, dim int)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html):

```
select
    array_column,
    array_agg(subscripts) subscripts
from (
    select
        array_column, 
        generate_subscripts(array_column, 1) subscripts
    from
        test_schema.test_table
    ) sub
group by 1;

 array_column | subscripts 
--------------+------------
 {2}          | {1}
 {3,16}       | {1,2}
 {5,12,6,2}   | {1,2,3,4}
 {51,4,2}     | {1,2,3}
(4 rows)
```

Comment: `generate_scripts` is simpler but notice that the OP may not want to eliminate the duplicates in the `array_column`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I don't think this actually eliminates duplicates, I modified my values for row 1 to ARRAY[5,5,5,5] and klin's answer still worked

Comment: @Dan I mean duplicate arrays between rows (2+ rows with the same array)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto - in practice there should be a unique field to group by or you can use `ctid` as a last resort. In Postgres there is no `generate_scripts`.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Ahh I understand, sorry about that. I failed to mention that on my real world implementation I'll have a column called "rowno" of type "serial", so I'll simply group by array_column and rowno, which fixes the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @klin Ok I meant `subscripts`

Answer (score 1):

```
select array_column, a
from
    test_table
    cross join lateral (
        select array_agg(a)
        from generate_series(1, array_length(array_column, 1)) s(a)
    ) s(a)
;
```